# How to send WebSocket close frame with status code to a browser?

Tags: java, websocket

My goal is to send WebSocket close frame with `/code/` and `/reason/`.

I am referencing from RFC6455 which says

```
If there is a body, the first two bytes of
   the body MUST be a 2-byte unsigned integer (in network byte order)
   representing a status code with value /code/ defined in Section 7.4.
   Following the 2-byte integer, the body MAY contain UTF-8-encoded data
   with value /reason/, the interpretation of which is not defined by
   this specification.
```

My expectation the Base Framing Protocol would be

```
first byte = FIN, RSV1, RSV2, RSV3, opcode
second byte = Mask, Payload len
third byte = /code/
fourth byte = /code/
fifth byte and so on = /reason/

for example code 1000 would be 1111101000.
third byte = 11111010
fourth byte = 0x00
```

What I have did:

1. Send a `unmasked close frame` without `/code/` or `/reason/`.

```
public static final byte[] Unmasked_Close_Frame = new byte[]{(byte) 0x88, 0};
```

What I want to do:

1. Send a WebSocket close frame with `/code/` 1000 and without `/reason/`

```
public static final byte[] Unmasked_Close_Frame = new byte[]{(byte) 0x88, 0, (byte) 0xFA, 0};
```

2. Send a WebSocket close frame with `/code/` 1000 and with `/reason/` no reason lol

```
public static final byte[] Unmasked_Close_Frame = new byte[]{(byte) 0x88, 13, (byte) 0xFA, 0, (byte) 110, (byte) 111, (byte) 32, (byte) 114, (byte) 101, (byte) 97, (byte) 115, (byte) 111, (byte) 110, (byte) 32, (byte) 108, (byte) 111, (byte) 108};
```

My expected result: The browser should close the websocket connection cleanly.

My actual result: The close frame sent by the server caused `error` event.

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:80");

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

My bad.

I was wrong on this part

```
for example code 1000 would be 1111101000.
third byte = 11111010
fourth byte = 0x00
```

this should be

```
for example code 1000 would be 1111101000.
third byte = 0x03
fourth byte = 11101000
```

and, the `Payload len` in close frame includes the `/code/` and `/reason/`.

So, the `Payload len` only can be `0` or `2` if you add `/code/` and `2 + reason length` if you have `/code/` and `/reason/`

For example,

Payload len = 2 + 13 = `/code/` + `/reason/`
code = 1000
reason = no reason lol

```
public static final byte[] Unmasked_Close_Frame = new byte[]{(byte) 0x88, 15, 3, (byte) 0xE8, (byte) 110, (byte) 111, (byte) 32, (byte) 114, (byte) 101, (byte) 97, (byte) 115, (byte) 111, (byte) 110, (byte) 32, (byte) 108, (byte) 111, (byte) 108};
```